# How do I programmatically get the state of UIBarButtonItems?

Tags: ios, state, uibarbuttonitem, uicontrol

With a `UIControl` such as a `UIButton` you can use something like
`myControl.state`
to figure out whether the control is currently being pressed down.

However, I need to do the same with some `UIBarButtonItems` (which are not derived from `UIControl`), so that I can stop my table from editing while one of them is pressed down.

Here's my code:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //other checks
    for(int b=0; b<self.toolbar.items.count; b++)
    {
        UIControl *currentControl= [self.toolbar.items objectAtIndex:b];
        if(currentControl.state==UIControlStateHighlighted)
        {
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Obviously, it doesn't work, since it assumes that `UIBarButtonItems` *can* be treated as `UIControls`, but how would I do what I'm trying to do here?

Comment: You are right, kind sir.

Comment: What functionality are you trying to pull off?

Comment: I have a table in my application where the cells can be swiped to enter edit mode and present a delete button. However, I was encountering bugs when the user entered edit mode on a cell while pressing down a button or one of the toolbar buttons at the same time. Therefore, I want to make it impossible to enter edit mode while the buttons are being held down. Just a polish thing.

Comment: So like if they hold down their finger on a button in a cell or somewhere and then hit the edit button while they are still holding down the first button?  Why not just disable editing mode during touchDown and re-enable the editing button when they touchUp

Comment: Actually, UIBarButtonItems only allow one action to be set, and they also don't allow you to pick which control event it's for.

Comment: Oh so you mean if they push down on a UIBarButtonItem and then push on ANOTHER UIBarButtonItem.  I thought you meant a UIButton for the first one then a UIBarButtonItem for the seecond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want more control over your `UIBarButtonItems` the best thing to do is to recreate them as `UIButtons` (using custom art, etc), and then use the `-initWithCustomView` of `UIBarButtonItem` to create button items from actual UIViews.

This will give you full access to the usual button interactions methods: the only downside is you won't get the nice bar button style by default, and you'll have to provide the art for this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem before. I couldn't fix it, so I moved on. Here is what I did:

Use ToolBar instead of navigation bar, then use UIButton instead of UIBarButtonItem inside the toolbar.

Comment: Why would you need to use a tool bar rather than a nav bar? You can add custom `UIBarButtonItems` to both navigation and tool bars.