# How do I make UIBarButton Work as Switch Given that UIBarButton Doesn't have Selected Property

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5, uibarbuttonitem

With normal button you can do

btn.selected = !btn.selected.

How would I pull that out with UIBarButton?

Comment: UIBarButtonItem *add = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addNewRow:)];
- (void)addNewRow:(UIButton *)sender (or) - (void)addNewRow:(UIBarButton *)sender.... both will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create UIBarButtonItem with the custom view

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setImage:normalImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setImage:selectedImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(btnClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
```

Then

```
-(void)btnClick:(id)sender{
UIBarButtonItem *item = (UIBarButtonItem *)sender;
UIButton *button = (UIButton *)item.customView;
[button setIsSelected:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a custom Button inside UIBarItem, remain one just do with you button.

```
UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:self.yourButton]

[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:barButton];
```

Then:

```
   self.yourButton.select = !self.yourButton.select;
```

Answer (score 1):

Idea 1. If you are creating your interface in IB, try dragging a standard UIButton object into the UIToolbar. This should encapsulate the UIButton inside a UIBarButton.
Set the UIBarButton object to be plain.
Create outlets to everything as usual.
Then you can use the standard button along with all it's lovely standard things like selected state in the toolbar.

Idea 2. I've pretty much given up on using toolbars as the controls are inflexible as you're finding. Now I just replace instances of UIToolbar with UIViews and do the small amount if code it needs to manage rotation, resizing etc... I've found it more flexible and let's me includes other controls more easily.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to have the  selected property through UIBarButtonItem straight away.  But you can achieve this by placing the UIButton and customizing it like a UIBarbutton.  This link will be more useful to you...[How do I programmatically get the state of UIBarButtonItems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209689/how-do-i-programmatically-get-the-state-of-uibarbuttonitems)